# Rename mixed-case tables in a single query

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

In my `PostgreSQL 9.2` database there are many tables having name with mixed cases,For example

`Tbl_Sales`,`Tbl_Purch`,`Tbl_logMnth`

What I want to do is

```
 alter table "Table1" rename to table1
```

but how to rename all mixed-case tables in my database in an easy way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following select to get the table(s) with mixed-cases in name

```
 SELECT  table_name ucase,lower(table_name) lcase
 FROM    information_schema.tables 
 where   table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and 
         table_schema = 'public' and 
         table_name ~ E'^[[:upper:]][^[:upper:]]'
```

PostgreSQL string function [**lower**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-string.html) and [**information_schema.tables**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/infoschema-tables.html)

and use PL/PGSQL [**SQL - DO**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-do.html) to rename all tables that have mixed-case

```
do
$$
declare 
rw record;
begin
for rw in 
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE  "'||t.ucase||'" RENAME to '||t.lcase||';'  execme from (
SELECT  table_name ucase, lower(table_name) lcase
FROM    information_schema.tables 
where   table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and 
        table_schema = 'public' and 
        table_name ~ E'^[[:upper:]][^[:upper:]]')t
loop
execute rw.execme ;
end loop;
end;
$$
```

Answer (score 3):

this is the query to use

> ALTER TABLE name
>       RENAME TO new_name

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would probably be to generate a series of dynamic *SQL* statements, in, say, *Python* or similar by querying the [`pg_tables` catalog](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-tables.html).

You could then iterate over that list for the schemas in which you're interested (or all of them if you want to do that, so long as they're user-created -- you should avoid any of the `pg_` ones, among others, as those are managed by *Postgres* itself) and check to see if the lowercase name is the same as the current name. If they are different, you can then generate the `ALTER TABLE` statement needed to rename the table, and then execute it, making sure to `COMMIT` your changes.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dece0/1/0) with an example of this.

Note how the `foo` table I created is listed in there.

I'd recommend white-listing by schema, say, `public` and any others you want. In the fiddle, for example, you wouldn't want to touch anything in the `pg_catalog` nor `information_schema` schemas. You could also filter by `tableowner` -- you would probably want to avoid, for example, anything owned by the **postgres** user.

Also, note that when creating tables, casing doesn't matter. If a table `foo` already exists, and I then try to create `Foo`, the error `ERROR: relation "foo" already exists` will result.